# How to obtain the sonar.pullrequest.key dynamically

Tags: docker, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, aws-codebuild, sonarcloud

I am setting PR decoration for my project and I am adding the following configuration in my **sonar-project.properties**:

```
sonar.pullrequest.provider=GitHub
sonar.pullrequest.github.repository=<repository>
sonar.pullrequest.base=main
sonar.pullrequest.branch=feature/*
sonar.pullrequest.key=5
```

However, the `sonar.pullrequest.key` I don't want it to be static but every new PR the analysis for the PR decoration is performed.

I am using Docker to install, analyze with Sonar and AWS Codebuild as CI/CD.

How can I pass the most recent PR always?

Answer (score 1):

For those use GitHub actions to do so, these might help:

```
sonar.pullrequest.key=${{github.event.pull_request.number}}
sonar.pullrequest.branch=${{github.head_ref}}
sonar.pullrequest.base=${{github.base_ref}}
```